# Prove that $n^2 -1$ is divisible by $8$, for every odd integer $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Prove that $n^2 - 1$ is divisible by $8$, for every odd integer $n$.

I tried to factorize and find something but still have no idea.

Comment: What did you get by factorising? Have you managed to prove *something*, even if it is weaker than the thing you are asked to prove?

Answer (score 1):

Since n is odd, n can be of form $8q+1, 8q+3, 8q+5$ or $8q+7 $.
If  $ n = 8q+1$ then $ n^2-1 = 8q(8q+2)$ If $n = 8q+3$ then $n^2-1 = 8(8q^2+6q+1)$
If $n = 8q+5$ then $n^2-1 = 8(8q^2+10q+3)$ and if $ n=8q+7$ then $n^2-1= 8(8q^2+14q+6)$.  We see that all of them are divisible by 8. Hence $n^2-1$ is divisible by 8 where n is an odd integer.

Answer (score 1):

An odd integer must be in the form of $2n-1$, so $(2n-1)^2-1=4n^2-4n = 4n(n-1)$

$n-1$ must be even, since $n$ is odd. Thus, $n-1$ must be a multiple of $2$. $2*4=8$, proving $n^2-1$ is divisible by $8$ for every odd integer $n$.

Comment: *Your* $n$ needn't be odd ...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Since it is odd, we can write $\;n=2k+1\;$ , so

$$n^2-1=(2k+1)^2-1=4k(k+1)$$